# Passing php's $_POST to a python script

Tags: python, php

As mentioned in the title, i am trying to pass the php `$_POST` array to a python script

I have the following php line:

```
echo shell_exec('python script.py ' . json_encode($_POST));
```

And this python code:

```
import sys
import json
import os.path

encodedinfo = sys.argv[1]
info = json.loads(encodedinfo);
print(info['id']);
```

i have found that the problem is with the `json.loads()` function, as if it is not commented the script does not reach the `print()` command.
How do i solve this?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Did you print out `encodedinfo`? Does it contain the whole JSON or just parts of it until the first space?

Comment: I have printed it out, it's a string like {key1: value1, key2: value2...}

The keys and values aren't placed between "", so maybe that's the problem, but i don't know how to fix it

I have also tested the json.loads() function with a sample json string, and it worked fine

Comment: Printed it out how/where? `json_encode` definitely adds the quote marks properly.

Comment: I printed it in the print() of the python script, and it echoed on my server without the quote marks.
The test json i used echoed with the quote marks on the server

Comment: Ok. That doesn't necessarily prove what was _sent_. If you put `echo 'python script.py ' . json_encode($_POST);` in the PHP you can see what the command will look like

Comment: Have you tried to apply `escapeshellarg` to the JSON?

Comment: Quotation marks are fine in command. The command looks like this `python script.py {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", ...}`. I have also tried using `escapeshellarg`, it still did not work